# Ionic keyboard overlay content

Tags: ios, ionic2

I have a question when I click to input, keyboard open and overlay bottom of the content. Earlier I had used ionic-plugins-keyboard, but after entering ios12 this plugin doesn't want work.

```
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.1",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "~2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "git+https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "~0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "~1.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
    "cordova-plugin-toast": "~1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "~5.3.2",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-html-minifier": "^0.1.8",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash._escapehtmlchar": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash.defaults": "^4.2.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "~2.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1": "2.0.1",
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-jscs": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.13",
    "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.4",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0",
    "jspm": "^0.16.46",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "wiredep": "^2.2.2",
    "yargs": "^3.31.0"
}
```

This issues on ios 11 and ios 12, earlier versions I was not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, this happened because `ion-content` `position: absolute`, I fixed it by `position: relative`.